# Trying to setup VPN and now i cannot access the internet

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have been using Ubuntu (version 20.04) for a number of years and decided I should expand my experience. I wanted to create a server at home and access it from the outside world. I have been following the instructions on https://serverspace.io/support/help/configuring-openvpn-on-ubuntu/ and it seemed to be going well until I rebooted the server machine at the end of the tutorial and now I cannot access the internet. I have attempted to undo all that I did, but still not working. I removed dnsmasq, I commented the lines that I had uncommented in server.conf, I removed the line at the end of sysctl.conf that was added. The only thing I have not addressed is the individual commands that work with the iptables, because I do not know how to address them.

When I check my ip address it is showing as 10.10.10.134,
Default Route is 10.10.10.254,
Primary DNS 10.10.10.254

This seems wrong, I think the machine is stuck in my local network and I don't know how to get it out.

Results of iptables -L

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination`

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination`

**Edit: (More information)**

The problem is isolated to one PC. The other PC in the house with a wired connection is fine and the laptop with the wireless connection is fine.

The PC that is not connecting, is communicating with the router. When I use Windows on the same PC, I am able to connect to the internet.

I have rewritten the 01-netcfg.yaml file to the following:

`network: version: 2 renderer: networkd ethernets: enp1s0: dhcp4: true dhcp6: true optional: true`

While the formatting is not accurate here, I followed the standards for this file.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one default route?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. Can someone give me the content of /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

Answer (score 0):

If your iptables rules are still set up wrong, this is probably what blocks you.

Try resetting them using the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

If that doesn't help, show us what `iptables -L` returns.

That may only be part of the problem however.

Comment: thank you for replying @Sebastian. I typed in the commands and rebooted, but still no intetrnet. The output for iptables -L is

'Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source  destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source  destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source  destination'  I apologize for the formatting, I am new to this site and am having difficulty getting the site to accept my formatting

Comment: Please add the output to your initial post by using the "Code Block" formatting. It doesn't work in comments I think. But from what it looks like, that doesn't seem to be the problem since there are no rules in it that could block you.